btrfs send/receive creates many directories with numeric names
I'm trying to replicate a btrfs subvolume used for backups onto another disk using btrfs send/btrfs receive. The subvolume is several terabytes in size so I expect the process to take a while.
So far the subvolume on the destination contains a large number of directories with numeric names, like this:
o133282512-18088-0
o133282513-18088-0
o133282539-18088-0
o133282554-18088-0
o133282555-18088-0
o133282556-18088-0
o133282557-18088-0
o133282558-18088-0
o133282559-18088-0
o133282570-18088-0

...

o95947528-15073-0
o95947529-15073-0
o95947530-15073-0
o95947531-15073-0
o95947532-15073-0
o95947533-15073-0
o95947534-15073-0
o95947535-15073-0
o95947536-15073-0
o95947537-15073-0

When I inspect the contents of these directories I see filenames that seem to have come from the filesystem I'm copying, for example one I checked contains a bunch of JPEG files consistent with it being a copy of the backup of part of my photo library.
So it seems I am getting some data files through, but btrfs hasn't (yet) replicated any of the directory structure of the source filesystem.
Is this normal behavior for btrfs send/receive? Will btrfs eventually reproduce the directory structure of the source subvolume?

Could btrfs send/receive "resort" those files into the proper directories? In my case, it didn't. So I had to stop using the send/receive method and instead use normal copy.
My setup:
source: mdadm-raid5-btrfs with data and meta DUP
target: btrfs-raid1 with data single and meta DUP

In my case it did (eventually, near the end of the send/receive) re-sort those files into the proper directories.
